# Multiple AWS routes with same Destination Cidr Blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to create two routes for two nat gateways that live in separate subnets. Is there a reason why they can't have a destination cidr block of 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: What would this configuration accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume that you are wanting to create a Highly Available network that is using **multiple NAT Gateways** in separate Availability Zones.

This is a common design requirement. Amazon EC2 instances in a private subnet that wish to communicate with the Internet require a **route** to a NAT Gateway (or a NAT Server). To remain highly available, you will need a **NAT Gateway in each Availability Zone** and a different route table for each Availability Zone.

[image: Highly Available VPC with multiple NAT Gateways]

Then:

- The Route Table for the private subnet in **Availability Zone A** would have a `0.0.0.0/0` route that points to **NAT Gateway A**.
- The Route Table for the private subnet in **Availability Zone B** would have a `0.0.0.0/0` route that points to **NAT Gateway B**.

Each route table can only have one entry for a given CIDR range. The VPC selects the most-restrictive CIDR range that matches, so the `0.0.0.0/0` entry will be the last one referenced.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very useful